# python set dict not exist, how can I handle it?

Tags: python

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

reader = sitk.ImageFileReader()
reader.SetFileName(filePath)
reader.ReadImageInformation()
img = reader.Execute()

meta = {
    "a": reader.GetMetaData('0'), <- if not exist return 'undeinfed'
    "b": reader.GetMetaData('1'),
    "c": reader.GetMetaData('2'),
}
```

I am javascript developer.
I want to set meta dict and it shows error which is 'Key '0' does not exist'.

It can be not exist how can I set meta in this case?

Comment: Wrap it into a function.

Comment: What is `reader.GetMetaData`? in any case, you can always handle the KeyError

Comment: It's a function of library

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Which library, and does it offer the ability to give a default value if none exists?

Comment: it's well unknown library and it shows error because it does not always have all keys of dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://simpleitk.org/doxygen/latest/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1ImageFileReader.html), the `ImageFileReader` class has a [`HasMetaDataKey()`](https://simpleitk.org/doxygen/latest/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1ImageFileReader.html#addcf2b5befca8ec7bdac52da747db2cd) boolean function. So you should be able to do something like this:

```py
meta = {
    "a": reader.GetMetaData('0') if reader.HasMetaDataKey('0') else 'undefined',
    "b": reader.GetMetaData('1') if reader.HasMetaDataKey('1') else 'undefined',
    "c": reader.GetMetaData('2') if reader.HasMetaDataKey('2') else 'undefined',
}
```

And you could do in one (long) line:

```py
meta = {m: reader.GetMetaData(k) if reader.HasMetaDataKey(k) else 'undefined'
        for m, k in zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['0', '1', '2'])}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use default dict

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda : 'xx') #<- Whatever value you want
d[10] #no value passed value automatically assinged to xx
d[11]=12 #value 12 assinged
#to get value you can use d.get(key)
print(d[10]) #prints 'xx'
print(d)
```

outputs

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001557B4B03A8>, {10: 'xx', 11: 12})
```

you get the idea you can modify according to your need

Comment: OP isn't talking about looking up values in a dictionary; they're talking about setting values in a dictionary when the expression intended for use as a value returns an error.